# Gran cantidad de peticiones de dos ips a hosting wordpress (¿Posible ataque?)

Tags: wordpress, seguridad, apache2

Muy buenas, 
Tengo en el hosting de mi web  en wordpress dos ips que me hacen peticiones head prácticamente a cada segundo. El servidor se mantiene pero cuando le doy caña o hay un ligero pico de visitas el servidor se sobrecarga.

Se trata de un vps en el que solo tengo 1 wordpress y tengo 2 GB de ram y un núcleo solo para esta web, por lo que la falta de recursos debe venir de algún sitio y creo que son estas peticiones:

> Ip1 - - [20/Dec/2018:12:07:05 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "-"
>   52
>
> Ip2 - - [20/Dec/2018:12:07:05 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "-"
>   52
>
> Ip1 - - [20/Dec/2018:12:07:05 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "-"
>   52
>
> Ip2 - - [20/Dec/2018:12:07:06 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "-"
>   52
>
> Ip2 - - [20/Dec/2018:12:07:06 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "-"
>   52
>
> Ip2 - - [20/Dec/2018:12:07:07 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "-"
>   52
>
> Ip1 - - [20/Dec/2018:12:07:07 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "-"
>   52

Esto se repite sin descanso todo el día, desde hace ya unas semanas.

¿Alguien me podría confirmar que puede ser un ataque o scrapeo de la web? ¿Y qué medidas debería tomar para que ya no se realicen estas peticiones?

Un saludo y gracias,

Comment: ¿has verificado de donde son esas ips? si no te interesan puedes meterlas en la lista negra del firewall.

Answer (score 2):

No sé yo si se trata de un ataque. Lo que sí puedo decirte es que se está intentando acceder a un recurso que se ha movido de ubicación, y ese es el mensaje de respuesta. Es posible que alguien (o algo) esté tratando de acceder reiteradamente a un recurso que ya no está donde estaba.

Si es siempre la misma IP, a bote pronto se me ocurre que bloquees las peticiones de esa IP desde tu servidor. Te dejo este enlace que te habla de las peticiones 301 y como tratarlas y gestionarlas:

https://miposicionamientoweb.es/redireccion-301/

Answer (score -1):

Es probable que sea **hotlinking**

Agrega lo siguiente a tu *.htacces*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|php|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]
```

> No olvides reemplazar tu dominio.